# Yii2 поиск по медели, условие IN

Tags: yii2

Всем привет!
Странно ведет себя поиск в модели по условию IN 
Допустим такой запрос на прямую к базе:

```
SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE type in (1,0)
```

отрабатывает прекрасно, находит 0-е типы
а вот аналогичный как бы запрос к модели:

```
$model_s=$model_p->find()->where(['in', 'type', [1,0]])->orderBy(['type'=>SORT_DESC])->all();
```

не возвращает 0, пока не напишешь вот так [0,1]
что я нетак делаю?

И второй вопрос - есть ли какая то возможность sql, который отправляет модель базе?

Comment: *не возвращает 0, пока не напишешь вот так [0,1]* Смотрите в генеральском логе, во что, в какой SQL-текст фреймворк транслирует запрос.

Comment: Генеральный лог - это какой runtime/logs/app.log ? так там только ошибки по запросам выводятся, как то можно посмотреть что модель отправляет в базу?

Comment: Посмотрел через дебаг
вот что эта модель шлет базе
SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE (user_id = '65') AND (`type`='0,1') ORDER BY `type` 
DESC

откуда берется AND (`type`='0,1'), если я передаю как бы type in(0,1)

Comment: Переделал запрос теперь так: (`type`='(0,1)')
почему операнд IN меняется на равно? 
пишу же вроде правильно ['in', 'type', (0,1), или не правильно?

Comment: Неправильно передаёте параметр. Как результат, поле `type` сравнивается не с двумя значениями `0` и `1`, а с одним строковым значением `'(0,1)'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за внимание, документацию я так понял надо проверять и проверять...
заработало только так ' type in ('.$get_event_type.')'
то есть когда я where перписал, а вот всякие ['in', 'type', '('.$get_event_type.')']
не работают.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$records = ModelName::find()
    ->where(['type' => [1, 0]])
    ->all();
```

Такой тип условия работает по разному в зависимости от типа параметра:

- если на входе `null`, то `['type' => null]` транслируется в `type IS NULL`
- если скалярное значение `['type' => 1]`, то `type = 1`
- если массив `['type' => [1, 2, 3]]`, то `type IN (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: KiTE - спасибо, но мне проще писать на чистом sql, а не плясать с бубном), тратя время на использование того, что реально не работает.

Comment: @Sergey P, можно и на чистом. SQL-билдер - это всего лишь инструмент, и его нужно применять там, где это уместно. И, чтобы понимать где уместно, а где - нет, его нужно знать. По моему опыту встроенный построитель сильно упрощает жизнь, когда нужно составлять сложные запросы на основе поисковых форм.